# How to hide items, in an API reply, from a db query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm currently using MVC with EF to have a small server with API querying a SQL database. But in the API reply I'm not able to hide some parameters.

The main object

```
public class AssetItem
{
   [Key]
   public Int32 AssetId { get; set; }
   public String AssetName { get; set; }

   public int OdForeignKey { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("OdForeignKey")]
   public OperationalDataItem OperationalDataItem { get; set; }
}
```

The other one:

```
public class OperationalDataItem
{
   [Key]
   public Int32 OperationalDataId { get; set; }
   public String Comunity { get; set; }

   public List<AssetItem> AssetItems { get; set; }
}
```

From what I have read, this should be ok, I have also set the context:

```
public AssetContext(DbContextOptions<AssetContext> options) : base(options)
{}

public DbSet<AssetItem> AssetItems { get; set; }
public DbSet<OperationalDataItem> OperationalDataItems { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<AssetItem>().HasOne(p => 
  p.OperationalDataItem).WithMany(b => b.AssetItems).HasForeignKey(p => 
  p.OdForeignKey);
}
```

And the seeding in program.cs

```
context.AssetItems.Add( 
  new AssetItem { AssetName = "Test test", OdForeignKey = 1, 
         OperationalDataItem  = 
            new OperationalDataItem {Comunity = "Comunity1" }});
```

So calling the API this results in:

```
{ "assetId":3,
  "assetName":"Test test",
  "odForeignKey":1,
  "operationalDataItem":null }
```

From what I read this is because of the lazy loading, how can I hide the result operationalDataItem?

In case is not possible i have of course try to query for it and give it back and it give something like:

```
{ "assetId":3,
  "assetName":"Test test",
  "odForeignKey":1,
  "operationalDataItem":
           { "operationalDataId":1,
             "comunity":"Comunity1",
             "assetItems":[
```

But in this case I would like to hide "assetsItems" in the reply to the FE.
How can I hide those parameters?

The API is quite simple, just an example code:

```
var todoItem = await _context.AssetItems.FindAsync((Int32)id);
var item = _context.OperationalDataItems.Find((Int32)todoItem.OdForeignKey);
todoItem.OperationalDataItem = item;
return todoItem
```

Comment: You could return a type that does not have the parameters you want to hide. Of course, you'd need to do some object-mapping then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data from the database, but you only want to fetch some properties, use Select. Usually this is more efficient than using Find, because you'll only transfer the data that you actually plan to use.

To fetch some properties of the assetItem that has primary key assetItemId:

```
var result = dbContext.AssetItems
    .Where(assetItem => assetItem.AssetItmId = assetItemId)
    .Select(assetItem => new
    {
        // Select only the properties that you plan to use
        Id = assetItem.AssertItemId,
        Name = assetItem.Name,

        OperationalData = new
        {
            // again, select only the properties that you plan to use
            Id = assetItem.OperationalData.OperationalDataId,
            Community = assetItem.OperationalData.Community,
        },
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or the other way round:

Fetch several properties of all (or some) OperationalDataItems, each with some properties of all (or some) of its AssetItems:

```
var result = dbContext.OperqationalDataItems
    .Where(operationalDataItem => ...)           // only if you don't want all
    .Select(operationalDataItem => new
    {
         Id = operationalDataItem.Id, 
         Community = operationalDataItem.Community

         AssetItems = operationalDataItem.AssetItems
            .Where(assetItem => ...)            // only if you don't want all its assetItems
            .Select(assetItem => new
            {
                // Select only the properties you plan to use:
                Id = assetItem.Id,
                ...

                // not useful: you know the value of the foreign key:
                // OperationalDataId = assetItem.OperationalDataId,
            })
            .ToList();
    })
    .ToList();      // or: FirstOrDefault if you expect only one element
```

Entity framework knows your one-to-many relation and is smart enough to know which (group-)join is needed for your query.

**Some side remarks**

You've declare your many-relation a `List<AssetItem>`. Are you sure that `operationalDataItem.AssetItems[4]` has a defined meaning? Wouldn't it be better to stick to the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx)? This would also eliminate the need for most attributes and / or fluent API

```
public class OperationalDataItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public String Comunity { get; set; }
   ...

   // Every OperationalDataItem has zero or more AssetItems (one-to-many)
   public virtual ICollection<AssetItem> AssetItems { get; set; }
}

public class AssetItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    ...

    // every AssetItem belongs to exactly one OperationalDataItem, using foreign key
    public int OperationDataItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual OperationalDataItem OperationalDataItem { get; set; }
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of a table are represented by the non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many)

Because I stuck to the conventions, no attributes nor fluent API is needed. Entity framework is able to detect the one-to-many relation and the primary and foreign keys. Only if I am not satisfied with the names or the types of the columns I would need fluent API.

Comment: From your reply i got `{ AssetId = 3, AssetName = "Test test", OperationalData = {{ OperationalDataId = 1, Comunity = Comunity1 }} }` that is fine. Issue is that the sign of the method is `public async Task<ActionResult<AssetItem>>` so I can't return that result because is an Anonymous Type.

On the side remarks i have followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships that use:  `public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }`

Comment: If you want to return the fetched data: create (or re-use) a class for the return value. About using a `List` instead of `ICollection`: The question remains: if you can't properly define the meaning of `AssetItems[4]`, why offer it as functionality? How are testers supposed to test your functionality if you can't properly define what your functions do?